# Does anyone know how to install the TASM patches? From version 4.1 to 5.3?

Tags: assembly, patch, tasm

So I downloaded TASM, started working with it until I realised my TASM versioni was 4.3 . 
I then browsed back to my TASM ZIP file that contained those patches, but I'm clueless on how to install them :S
Apparently I'm missing a PATCH.RTP file...
Help? :(

Comment: Unless you've got a large codebase written in TASM syntax I'd suggest switching to NASM. It can be used to write real mode programs, as well as protected mode programs (using e.g. the WDOSX DOS extender).

Comment: Japeth's JWASM would also be an option...

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the 5.3 patch?

The patch is composed of

- two `.rtp` files that contain the data to patch in the `tasm32.exe` and `td32.exe` Tasm executables
- a `patch.exe` tool that will process the `.rtp` files
- a batch file to automate the patch deployment.

All the files are usually packaged together in a `.zip` file.

The basic usage of `patch.exe` is `patch file.rtp`, while the `.rtp` file is in the same directory than the target file to be patched.